# How to left join Excel table to a table in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerpivot

I have a table (`tbl1`) in an Excel file with about 70k rows. I have linked that table into Power Pivot. There is another table (`tbl2`) in SQL Server with millions of rows that I need to left join to the table in my Excel file on

```
tbl1.[Member Number] = tbl2.[memid]
```

What query should I use to do it without having to import the whole `tbl2` from SQL Server (throws error on Power Pivot due to memory constraints)?

Preferred environment is Power Pivot, but I do have SQL Sever Management Studio. I don't have WRITE permission in the server where `tbl2` is located. I do however have WRITE access in a different server.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options spring to mind:

- Get more memory/64 bit Excel and use PowerPivot as you are currently trying to do. If you are working on 32bit excel then you are effectively constrained to using 1gb of RAM whereas on 64bit you can use everything you've got. 64bit Powerpivot can potentially deal with hundreds of millions of records.
- Read the SQL data and your csv into R, do the join and either write the output to your WRITE db or save as CSV to feed into PowerPivot. Although R has a steep initial learning curve, doing this kind of thing with the dplyr library is straightforward.
- Dump your SQL table to csv and read both that your current csv into the WRITE db and do the join in your PowerPivot SQL query.

Which works best probably depends on the skills you have and how often you are doing this. I'd probably go down the 'R' route as you can set it up as a scheduled job.

Comment: Thank you! You saved my day and my future career. I happen to be familiar with R from college, and always wanted an opportunity to use it on a daily basis on my job, but never really thought about joining tables on R. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Import the Excel file into the SQL server where you have WRITE access, do the join there and import the data from this server. Any problem you see with this approach?

Comment: Surely tables 1 and 2 need to be on the same server to do a join on import to PowerPivot.